# Why won't my own domain not showing my page but heoku site will?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, browser, dns

So I finally finished up my own portfolio site, and took it live on heroku. Afterwards, I added my domain from google domains. I think that I added it properly, but I might be missing something. Domains seem a little more complicated than I had initially anticipated. Anyways, my heoku app works fine, but my own domain website does not load properly, saying: "This site can’t provide a secure connection."

They are both live, and you can take a look for yourself.

[heroku-domiain](http://mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com)

[my domain](http://mikevkc.dev)

My domain will load on mobile, but then doesn't load my javascript properly.

here are my logs when I attempt to visit my domain:

```
lication Logs
2019-12-06T23:50:05.718561+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-06T23:50:05.718497 #4]  INFO -- : [7c52f1b6-f26a-4ff4-8d82-f2f5369722d1] Completed 200 OK in 1727ms (Views: 1649.1ms | ActiveRecord: 25.4ms)
2019-12-06T23:50:05.810532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-bf67060ba9efb9d9ec0f59de9a7e89f3a10acc8e48b0cada9fb6c56e0d87be01.css" host=www.mikevkc.dev request_id=56567f44-7be2-4c08-a7fb-9bed9b067176 fwd="35.230.49.100" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=36878 protocol=http
2019-12-07T00:28:08.288450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-12-07T00:28:08.291037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-12-07T00:28:09.691960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-12-07T00:28:09.720961+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726372+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2019-12-07 00:28:09 +0000 ===
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726443+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726630+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-12-07T00:28:10.003082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

And here are the logs after it loads when visiting the heroku domain:

```
2019-12-06T23:50:05.718561+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-06T23:50:05.718497 #4]  INFO -- : [7c52f1b6-f26a-4ff4-8d82-f2f5369722d1] Completed 200 OK in 1727ms (Views: 1649.1ms | ActiveRecord: 25.4ms)
2019-12-06T23:50:05.810532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-bf67060ba9efb9d9ec0f59de9a7e89f3a10acc8e48b0cada9fb6c56e0d87be01.css" host=www.mikevkc.dev request_id=56567f44-7be2-4c08-a7fb-9bed9b067176 fwd="35.230.49.100" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=36878 protocol=http
2019-12-07T00:28:08.288450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-12-07T00:28:08.291037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-12-07T00:28:09.691960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-12-07T00:28:09.720961+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726372+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2019-12-07 00:28:09 +0000 ===
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726443+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2019-12-07T00:28:09.726630+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-12-07T00:28:10.003082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-12-07T01:31:55.485155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2019-12-07T01:31:55.488917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-12-07T01:32:02.315207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 53808 -e production`
2019-12-07T01:32:08.147650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563796+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563848+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production 
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563851+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563853+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563855+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563857+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563859+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563861+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:53808
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563863+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2019-12-07T01:32:09.563865+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:09.563677 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63] Started GET "/" for 136.35.45.198 at 2019-12-07 01:32:09 +0000
2019-12-07T01:32:09.565181+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:09.565082 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2019-12-07T01:32:09.647491+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:09.647373 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-12-07T01:32:12.930560+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:12.930398 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63]   Rendered shared/_portfolio-cards.html.erb (1.9ms)
2019-12-07T01:32:13.030173+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:13.030032 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3379.5ms)
2019-12-07T01:32:13.040434+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:13.040333 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (3.1ms)
2019-12-07T01:32:13.041796+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-07T01:32:13.041720 #4]  INFO -- : [60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63] Completed 200 OK in 3476ms (Views: 3396.0ms | ActiveRecord: 29.6ms)
2019-12-07T01:32:13.046283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=60fdc3cf-6019-43db-93c6-b293296b5d63 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3484ms status=200 bytes=9495 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.314753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/packs/js/map-e2b62178eb7228680311.js" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=4b64ae80-0073-46fd-a2d3-ed2a3fa46b83 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.178259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-bf67060ba9efb9d9ec0f59de9a7e89f3a10acc8e48b0cada9fb6c56e0d87be01.css" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=b1414869-7cfc-4585-8089-f0f74b972dd6 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.280313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/packs/js/application-41e205ec9f72afd0012d.js" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=8cea5b64-068c-4aad-af40-d1dae424b97f fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.222936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/profilepic-b6ef53852c46abf96a1e84cc1ad1a3f01153e033bc681f98e2304e3152a9e893.jpg" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=a43e2da3-a3ab-4fef-bfd6-1f488d1f5257 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.418195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/popps-15914c7c88e94a7443b3489d3382cb4227478ec9b95124749bcc5d0d98f7204e.jpg" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=d5304651-1d91-402b-8fcf-0c3130432d53 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.262668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-61b49b9d722c087b2e2f109f0460847b42f654f1c8c4f601bd33e3136ab226d7.js" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=dee26750-e852-46c0-90f9-f84f14339dc0 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.367629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/lipic-5216bde6c496f48870d0151b4a2e1c8be0eae1f730df70f241e152aa23216e54.jpg" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=86d16e27-961d-4c3e-9d81-a45e7ac16689 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.368402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bell-hour-6418304986226f20d19ce83728d6b260d6d2a2c571cb2e2c1234585c0933012e.jpg" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=eb1eb0f6-9e61-47f1-b757-b818189a18aa fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.949834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-e5c1d9e7bdeaf3372dee724d175d25aca879ed52ae9afd018f503e9d74e09b50.woff2" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=ddaea96b-2de6-450e-bc12-99fcc62f5ecc fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.947480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-08aa3a5ee68a21d5771a70b20495b6da1c0f996c46982cd1b0447ad2db730d11.woff2" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=148f4b52-ee23-4ba9-b8b0-e7fe812008ea fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:13.958144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-c885e9f2017a2ed7075db9e876d40a04aa3208114443803bdb120a34afd3b1d6.woff2" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=f4af1edf-2ad4-40e9-a619-36c26d431a56 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:14.167728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=19d715f5-1239-40ec-98bf-067dfbdcfc6a fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-12-07T01:32:16.339653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/type-09d61a30abad860f1bed67840988a7464a7c88ef1bcf075fabbdb51f0e71dc75.mp4" host=mike-v-kc.herokuapp.com request_id=2c46aaa0-75b2-41b4-a623-92dd58e0b737 fwd="136.35.45.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

I think that the bug lies in the domain settings somewhere, but if you have any clues, please let me know what you think.

Comment: Post your logs.

Comment: Just made the edit

Comment: One is looking for http and the other is looking at https (SSL).  You need to configure SSL, which Heroku will provide the certs for free if you're paying for your dyno.

Comment: Well that worked. I found the dyno plans and the difference between them for SSL on custom domains. But that is really odd that the mobile site came through while the desktop site did not.